# Why in IE loading image not show at center bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Why in IE loading image not show at center bottom of page ?

This function are load content on load page and load content on scroll to bottom.

first, load page `index.php` you will see loading image at center bottom of page.

But i test on `ie 7,8` loading not show at center bottom of page , How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
// on submit form call function code //
$("#f1").submit(send_requests());
</script>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="f1">
    <input type="hidden" name="something"/>
    </form>
        <div id="loading" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: fixed; bottom: 135px; right: 50%; width: 36px; height: 24px; z-index: 999999;">
            <img src="http://auu-like.com/assets/img/loading.gif"/>
        </div>
        <div id="demoajax">

<script>
function send_requests(){
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#f1').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
}
// on load page call function code //
$(document).ready(send_requests());
</script>
```

test1.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="data_to_page_3" value="<?PHP echo $_POST[color_check]; ?>"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data_to_page_3 = $("#data_to_page_3").val();
 var ajax_arry=[];
 var ajax_index =0;
 var sctp = 100;
 $(function(){
   $('#loading').show();
 $.ajax({
         url:"test2.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"userdate="+data_to_page_3+"&actionfunction=showData&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
           $('#loading').hide();
          $('#demoajax').html(response);           
        }       
       });
    $(window).scroll(function(){       
       var height = $('#demoajax').height();
       var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(ajax_arry.length>0){
       $('#loading').hide();
       for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
         ajax_arry[i].abort();
       }
    }
       var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
       var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();      
             if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) && (isload=='true')){
           $('#loading').show();
       var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
         url:"test2.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"userdate="+data_to_page_3+"&actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
           $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
           $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
           $('#loading').hide();           
          $('#demoajax').append(response);       
        }       
       });
       ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;

       }
    return false;   
 if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
    });
});
</script>
```

test2.php

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type='hidden' class='nextpage' value='".($page+1)."'><input type='hidden' class='isload' value='true'>
```

Comment: Holy crap! So many `<br>`? Use CSS!

Comment: `<br>` is only example for ask on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

In your both files wherever you have used .hide() and .show() replace it with the following two changes :

```
   .hide() with .css('display','none');
   .show() with .css('display','block');
```